# How to prevent other from using face image to fool Deep Learning model?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I'm trying developing an application to login with face with Neural Network and run in real time, how to prevent other from using my face image to login?

Answer (score -1):

If you are a developing a live feed video-based recognition system then you need to train the network to learn to distinguish between images within a live feed and no image.

Comment: Thanks @Srinath. So far I have just implemented CNN, do you suggest using RNN when mentioning about distinguishing images within a live feed or not?

Comment: Yes, you might need both, CNN and RNN, aka Convolutional Recurrent neural network.